# Php variable inside mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a database with CREATE DATABASE command, but instead it gives me an error.
this is my code:

```
$db_usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (! $con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    test();
}

function test()
{
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE '$db_usr'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

It always returns "Undefined variable"

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query`, since it's deprecated. If you can't/aren't going to use PDO, use the `mysqli` library. Please see [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: You [**should not use mysql_* functions**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)!

Comment: firstly change 
`mysql_connect("localhost","root");`  // you forgot to keep password

Comment: You are creating one database per user? Are you sure this is the best way to go? It's probably a good idea to look up 'database normalisation'.

Comment: Actually yes, but I already figure it out to normalize it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$db_user` variable isn't accessible inside your function scope and that's the reason why you're getting that error.

If you want the variable to be used inside your function, then pass it as a function parameter, like so:

```
function test($db_usr)
{
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE `$db_usr`";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

If this involves user input, then your database query is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should always validate user input (recommended way is to use MySQLi or PDO with parameterized queries).

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain or suggest improvements?

Comment: Also using backtick character instead of single quote, Not?

Comment: add `else
{
 test($db_usr)  }`  in else part

Comment: Single quote is a syntax error here. Should use backtick (ascii 96). To prevent SQL injection, he should replace backticks with double backticks in $db_usr (using str_replace).

Comment: @hallaji: Derp. Fixed that :)

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
function test()
    {
        $db_usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
        $query= "create database ".$db_usr ."";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
```